# gtkmm delays output via stderr stdout

Tags: c++, c++11, gtkmm

hy,

I found out, that gtkmm is delaying the output I wrote to std::cerr/std::cout until the Gtk::Window is closed.

But after a bit of researching I found out, that this is not always true. For example, if I add a Button to the Window, and I show the button, outputs on STDOUT and STDERR are working as exepcted.

To test this, I have written an MWE: (If you uncomment the line _button.show();, you would see, that output is not delayed. But if you don't show the button, the output is delayed, until the window is closed.)

Also I have addedd a ofstream, which outputs the contents in both cases directly to /tmp/test.

```
#include <gtkmm/window.h>
#include <gtkmm/button.h>
#include <gtkmm/application.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

class window_t : public Gtk::Window {
public:
    window_t(void);

private:
    Gtk::Button _button;
};

window_t::window_t(void): _button("Click ME") {
    add(_button);
    //_button.show();
    std::cerr << "construct-cerr" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "construct-cout" << std::endl;
    std::cout.flush();
    std::cerr.flush();
    std::ofstream file("/tmp/test");
    file << "construct-file" << std::endl;
    file.close();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "com.example.test");
    window_t gtkmm_window;
    return app->run(gtkmm_window);
}
```

You can compile this code by:

```
g++  main.cpp -o main `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-3.0`  -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -Werror -Wcast-qual -Wcast-align -Wconversion -fdiagnostics-color=auto -g -O2 -std=c++11
```

Why does gtkmm delay outputs to STD(OUT|ERR) and how can I prevent this?

I am using gcc version 4.9.2 and gtkmm 3.14.

Comment: On my box your program outputs to cerr and cout with and without the line `_button.show();`. The program runs as expected. Sorry, I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hmm, which version of gtkmm and what os are you using? I am using debian jessie.

Comment: os: 4.1.4-200.fc22.x86_64; g++ (GCC) 5.2.0; gtkmm 3.16.0; gtk+ 3.16.6